# multiple post variables on same line PHP

Tags: forms, http-post

I'm not a programmer and I'm trying to alter an opensource Ajax contact form.

The email message which is to be sent from the form is not including all the fields of the contact form; only the first and the last. (first_name & themessage)

This is [send.php](http://pastebin.com/LpvaHQi3)

Dreamweaver highlights the first and last fields correctly, but those in the middle are not highlighted, indicating there is a coding problem (which I can't see).

Why aren't all the $POST variables being sent via email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several instances of `$POST` which should instead be [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).